# How does NASA compare with other space agencies in terms of RoI (in terms of science: papers published per $ invested)

Tags: nasa, research, cost, esa, jaxa

How does NASA's funding compare to other space agencies' funding? How many papers are they publishing and how many US patents do they have? Compare different space agencies in terms of 
number of patents per dollar funded
and
number of research papers published per dollar funded
and
number of papers published in Science or Nature (or an equally reputed space studies journal) per dollar funded

Comment: You are asking for a great deal of research. None of this data is easily available. And you are asking it for several different agencies, too, and comparison among them. Have you done any research on this yourself?

Comment: Have you tried browsing data.gov? I know, for example, that NASA budgetary and actual spending information is easily accessible there. Not as sure about volume of papers published.

Comment: I voted to close as "too broad". While a good question should not be immediately answerable via a quick browser search, a good question should not ask people to do untold amounts of research.

Comment: Moreover, "papers published per dollars invested" is not a good metric of return on investment. Much of NASA's budget is devoted to areas where the subject material is ITAR-restricted; publication is strictly verboten. (Similar concepts apply to other space agencies.)

Comment: @DavidHammen ITAR restriction is a good point that I didn't even bother to comment on. Also, I agree the question is too broad, but I'll leave it to the community to decide.

Comment: I agree its too much to expect from a forum such as this, "too broad" being the closest "close" response. By way of consolation to the OP, the question has relevance, its just a little intractable. I wouldn't be surprised if every space agency has at some point been tasked to audit its effectiveness and served some glowing report back to national government. Perhaps try thinking out how to search for such a thing. There's a good chance of finding whitewash but it would be an interesting learning experience along the way.